# Checkbox appears and disappears after multiple clicks on one checkbox

Tags: python, checkbox, kivy

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.properties import BooleanProperty
from kivy.lang import Builder

Builder.load_string('''
<MyWidget>:
    CheckBox:
        group: "Zone "
        active: root.odrzuc
        on_state: self.active
    CheckBox:
        group: "Zone "
        active: root.decyduj
        on_state: self.active

''')

class MyWidget(BoxLayout):
    odrzuc = BooleanProperty(False)
    decyduj = BooleanProperty(True)


class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return MyWidget()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

I want to click on one of the checkbox and it will turn on and the other turn off. I can block them using 'on_state: self.active', but I do not know how to unblock one, when the second one is blocked and vice versa.

Comment: In kivy a checkbox is a radiobutton.

Comment: Ah sorry, please see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You should give them a group:

```
group: 'my-group'
```

and set this:

```
allow_no_selection: False
```

[Documentation](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.behaviors.togglebutton.html#kivy.uix.behaviors.togglebutton.ToggleButtonBehavior.allow_no_selection)